# How to get only distinct values from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I am trying to iterate through a column in a text file, where each entry has only three choices  `A, B, and C`.

I want to identify the number of different types of choices `(another text file has A, B, C, and D)`, but if I iterate through each element in the column with a `100 entries` and add it to a list, I'll have multiple repetitions of each type. For example, if I do this, the list might read `[A,A,A,B,C,C,D,D,D,B,B...]`, but I want to remove the extraneous entries and just have my list show the distinguishable types `[A,B,C,D]`, regardless of how many entries there were.

Any ideas how I might reduce a list with many common elements to a list with only the different distinguishable elements displayed? Thanks!

Desired Output:

`[A, B, C, D]`

Comment: would help if you posted a snippet of the `txt` and any code you attempted

Comment: @Ferreroire, you can accept the answer along with upvote if you feel that solves your requirement that way it will be removed from un-answered queue.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## This is what you needed with `set()`:

```
>>> lst1 = ['A','A','A','B','C','C','D','D','D','B','B']
>>> list(set(lst1))
['A', 'B', 'D', 'C']
```

## Another solution `OrderedDict` to keep the order of keys during insertion.

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(lst1))
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

## In case you have liberty to use pandas then try below ones..

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> drop_dups  = pd.Series(lst1).drop_duplicates().tolist()
>>> drop_dups
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

In case you are looking for common values between two files:

```
$ cat getcomn_vals.py
#!/python/v3.6.1/bin/python3
def print_common_members(a, b):
    """
    Given two sets, print the intersection, or "No common elements".
    Remove the List construct and directly adding the elements to the set().
    Hence assigned the dataset1 & dataset2 directly to set()
    """

    print('\n'.join(s.strip('\n') for s in a & b) or "No common element")

with open('file1.txt') as file1, open('file2.txt') as file2:
    dataset1 = set(file1)
    dataset2 = set(file2)
    print_common_members(dataset1, dataset2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was very helpful!

Answer (score 6):

There is a data structure called `set` in python that do not allow duplicates.
This might help you out.

[documentation for set() at docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Answer (score 0):

We could use *itertools.groupby* and `sorted` to get this list of unique elements

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('text.txt') as f:
    content = [line.strip('\n') for line in f]

l = [k for k, g in groupby(sorted(content))]
print(l)
# ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```